# ploty annotations overlap when two data points are in the same possition

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly scatter plot that has two point in the same position, with two different annotations. 
When I hover over this point in the graph I only see one annotation, and I want to see both. 
Is this possible?

An example code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [1,1]
y = [1,1]
text = ['a','b']
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, text=text))
fig.show()
```

and it's output:

[image]

Comment: (1,1) and b are the hover annotations, I believe. In that case the plot is showing both the hover annotations. Isn't it?

Comment: No, 'a' and 'b' are the two annotations